# What is a good language for web-based games?

Tags: web-applications, language-agnostic

I'd like to play around with writing some very small, simple web-based games (checkers, Conway's Game of Life, etc). I started looking into Java applet tutorials, but my years of frustration with freezing Java applets had me wondering if there were better and easier development languages to invest my time on. What's a good "starter" language for web game development?

Comment: I think it will depend on the game, but many web-based complex games are made with Shockwave. For instance: http://www.habbo.com/

Comment: Shockwave is somewhat on it's way out. Flash is being used in many places that Shockwave once would have been. I wouldn't recommend learning it any time soon.

Comment: According to http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/shockwaveplayer/, Shockwave is installed on 57% of all internet-enabled PCs. That is not a good percentage at all, and it's only decreasing. Stay away from it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplest:  JavaScript
Most used:  Flash
Up and coming:  Silverlight
On the decline:  Java, Shockwave

Advice:  If you're doing something simple, Javascript is fine.  Flash is a good option from there, as there's a lot of examples to learn from.  Silverlight is good, but you'll have fewer examples to take advantage of.

If you want to be able to take advantage of many gaming portals, however, to get your game out to more people--Flash is really what most of them have focused around, and it'll be harder (not impossible) to distribute to others if you're not using Flash.

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight, calling Silverlight "up and coming" seems a little unwise now that Microsoft is discontinuing it....

Answer (score 10):

Flash is the platform of choice for small web-based games. As someone else has said, Silverlight may finally be reaching a state where it's usable for this as well. From what I understand, Sun is doing a renewed push with Applets but I think it may be too little, too late.

edit: link for posterity: [OSFlash.org](http://osflash.org/)

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to just create a client-side game? Then Flash or Silverlight would do.

But you probably want to keep track of high-scores and other statistics. For this the clientside game should call a web service so the browser doesn't have to switch pages. In that case, using C# for the server-side code and Silverlight for the client will keep you focused on a single development language.

Comment: Nice point, mentioning the potential server side aspects.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript + canvas tag for graphics works nice. IE doesn't have it yet, but it will.

Comment: IE supporst VML (a competing format to SVG) which can be used to implement canvas in IE: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Answer (score 3):

Focusing in on the "starter language" bit, I find it hard to recommend anything *other* than Silverlight.  The combination of the Visual Studio IDE and the wealth of documentation make it very newbie friendly.  Somebody even built [a basic 3D rendering engine](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using Flash, or the new version of Silverlight is getting to a good point you could start to do some excellent things with it.